# How can i connect two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have tables namely users and list respectively. I have two fields in users table and what i need to do is i want to connect two tables so that each user can contain number of entries in the list table and i wanted to fetch the list based on the user.

Comment: can you provide your table structure?

Comment: Sorry, structure in the sense?

Comment: @LogeshMohanasundaram I think Omesh wants the definition of these two tables, to see what they have in common, to create a join for your query.

Comment: Structure means table and fields of that table for your both tables.

Comment: mysql> SHOW TABLES; and mysql> DESCRIBE Your_Table;... here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html

Comment: Sorry i dont have any field in common. Actually iam new to this.

Comment: @LogeshMohanasundaram I think you are looking for Joining tables. Please reffer this link. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Comment: @LogeshMohanasundaram Having re-read your question, are you saying that you have these two completely unrelated tables at the moment, and in fact you'd like to create a third table which holds the relationships between the other two?

Comment: consider for example i want to save the username in user table and some entries like position etc in list table. consider there are more than one position for a single user and i wanted to fetch all the entries for the particular user. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN list ON users.id_user = list.id_user
```

This will output everything from table users and table lists, repeating users for each list.

NOTE: To do this you must have the user identifier in both tables.

You can add a WHERE condition to search for specific user name or something like that.
Please provide your users and list table structure for more help.

Check this example for creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id_user` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`user_email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
)

CREATE TABLE `list` (
`id_list` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_user` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`list_name` INT(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_list`)
)
```

Add some data to both tables and run the example above to see the result.

Comment: Username and age in users table and postion in list table. consider i have two username and more than 10 entries in the position. The two users have more than one position how can i describe or fetch the positions based on the username.

Comment: oh so i need any entry to be same in both the table. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a FOREIGN KEY relationship, a fundamental relational database concept. A search in the MySQL documentation for this term should turn up some useful documentation for you.